# How can I check for duplicates 24 hours apart in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from a SQL query, that looks comparable to this setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7],
'ID_Type': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
'Type_A_Value': [10, None, 10, None, None, None, None, 30, None, 55, 40, None, None, None],
'Type_B_Value': [None, None, None, 10, 11, 26, None, None, None, None, None, 19, None, None],
'Type_C_Value': [None, 4.3, None, None, None, None, 89, None, 12.3, None, None, None, 27, 55],
'Datetime': ['2022-10-03 08:00:00', '2022-10-01 09:00:00', '2022-10-02 08:00:00',
             '2022-10-01 11:00:00', '2022-10-02 11:00:00', '2022-10-02 13:00:00',
             '2022-10-01 14:00:00', '2022-10-01 15:00:00', '2022-10-02 07:00:00',
             '2022-10-01 14:00:00', '2022-10-01 15:00:00', '2022-10-02 07:00:00',
             '2022-09-01 14:00:00', '2022-10-01 01:00:00'] })
```

I'm trying to find a way to check for duplicates that are exactly 24 hours apart. Duplicates in general might be ok, but if the data is the same at 10 AM on the 10th and then at 10 AM on the 11th, I would like to highlight this, perhaps with a boolean column.

Summary of what I have tried so far:

- Sorting the dataframe and indexing by DateTime

  ```
   df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
   df = df.sort_values(['ID_Type', 'ID', 'Datetime'])
   df = df.set_index('Datetime')
  ```
- Using the df.shift function (doesn't work if using Datetime as Index and gives NotImplementedError if not an index)

  ```
  df['24HoursAgo'] = df['Datetime'].shift(-1, freq='24H')
  ```
- Creating a boolean column that checks if values 24 hours apart are the same (flawed because it won't consider the Device ID either)

```
grouped_df['SameValue24hoursApart'] = grouped_df['Type_A_Value'] == grouped_df['Type_A_Value'].shift(-1, freq='24H')
```

Essentially what I need is to be able to group by Device Type and ID (or just ID, since an ID cannot have more than one Type) and then check if that ID has data duplicates, of its respective Type column, that are 24 hours apart

(edited to include example duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have such data in your example, but you can indeed use a sorted comparison:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df['24HoursAgo'] = (df
   .sort_values(['ID_Type', 'ID', 'Datetime'])
   .groupby(['ID_Type', 'ID'])['Datetime']
   .diff().eq(pd.Timedelta('24h'))
)
```

Output:

```
    ID ID_Type  Type_A_Value  Type_B_Value  Type_C_Value            Datetime  24HoursAgo
0    1       A          10.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-03 08:00:00       False
1    3       C           NaN           NaN           4.3 2022-10-01 09:00:00       False
2    1       A          10.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-02 10:00:00       False
3    2       B           NaN          10.0           NaN 2022-10-01 11:00:00       False
4    2       B           NaN          18.0           NaN 2022-10-01 12:00:00       False
5    2       B           NaN          26.0           NaN 2022-10-02 13:00:00       False
6    3       C           NaN           NaN          89.0 2022-10-01 14:00:00       False
7    1       A          30.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 15:00:00       False
8    3       C           NaN           NaN          12.3 2022-10-02 07:00:00       False
9    4       A          55.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 14:00:00       False
10   4       A          40.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 15:00:00       False
11   5       B           NaN          19.0           NaN 2022-10-02 07:00:00       False
12   6       C           NaN           NaN          27.0 2022-09-01 14:00:00       False
13   7       C           NaN           NaN          55.0 2022-10-01 01:00:00       False
```

Alternatively, if you want to use all columns in the comparison, then you can add 24h to the Datetime and compute a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

out = df.merge(df.assign(Datetime=df['Datetime'].add(pd.Timedelta('24h')))
                 .reset_index(), how='left')
```

If any duplicate, this will add the index in the "index" column:

```
    ID ID_Type  Type_A_Value  Type_B_Value  Type_C_Value            Datetime  index
0    1       A          10.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-03 08:00:00    NaN
1    3       C           NaN           NaN           4.3 2022-10-01 09:00:00    NaN
2    1       A          10.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-02 10:00:00    NaN
3    2       B           NaN          10.0           NaN 2022-10-01 11:00:00    NaN
4    2       B           NaN          18.0           NaN 2022-10-01 12:00:00    NaN
5    2       B           NaN          26.0           NaN 2022-10-02 13:00:00    NaN
6    3       C           NaN           NaN          89.0 2022-10-01 14:00:00    NaN
7    1       A          30.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 15:00:00    NaN
8    3       C           NaN           NaN          12.3 2022-10-02 07:00:00    NaN
9    4       A          55.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 14:00:00    NaN
10   4       A          40.0           NaN           NaN 2022-10-01 15:00:00    NaN
11   5       B           NaN          19.0           NaN 2022-10-02 07:00:00    NaN
12   6       C           NaN           NaN          27.0 2022-09-01 14:00:00    NaN
13   7       C           NaN           NaN          55.0 2022-10-01 01:00:00    NaN
```

Comment: If I want to highlight both values as True how could I edit this script? Similarly, if I want to look for values that are within, say 5% (e.g. 100 and 105 would be treated as a duplicate)

Comment: The easiest might be to perform a double `merge` once by adding 24h, the other by subtracting it. Can you update the question with a valid example (to have at least one duplicate) and I'll update

Comment: Yes, updated to include a true duplicate, and where two values 24 hours apart are within 5% of each other